# Splitting a comma separated string to separate strings within a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, split, string-formatting

I have a input string like this:

```
pentavac-xim, revaxis, tetravac-xim
imovax polio, pediacel
act-hib, rage diploide
imogam rage pa, imovax polio
dt vax, tetavax
```

I want the Output string to displayed as:

```
['pentavac-xim', 'revaxis', 'tetravac-xim']
['imovax polio', 'pediacel']
['act-hib', 'rage diploide']
['imogam rage pa', 'imovax polio']
['dt vax', 'tetavax']
```

The problem is when I use split on the input string, for a product which should be treated as a single string, is converted into 2 separate strings, example:

imogam rage pa = ['imogam', 'rage', 'pa'] which is incorrect . It should be :
['imogam rage pa']. How to solve this

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to get help with your code, please post it. We need to see what you have done in order to explain how to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
input_string = 'pentavac-xim, revaxis, tetravac-xim'
output = input_string.split(', ')
print(output)
```

> Outputs: ['pentavac-xim', ' revaxis', ' tetravac-xim']

Comment: @Swordsman That's great to hear! If it solved your problem, I'd appreciate if you can click the check mark by my post (to accept it as the answer you were looking for)

Comment: this result the extra space in each string. Use lstrip function which remove the leading space from each sub-strings.

Comment: This is not true anymore, I edited the answer to make `', '` delimiter instead of `','`

Comment: Yeah thanks @BenoîtPilatte

Comment: @Usman that's a good catch that I missed, but like BenoîtPilatte said he already edited my answer to fix that mistake

Comment: okay great (y) 
Thanks @BenoîtPilatte & Reedinationer

Answer (score 4):

Splitting on commas should be just fine. This should work fine:

```
some_string = "imogam rage pa, imovax polio"
print(some_string.split(', '))
```

output:

```
['imogam rage pa', 'imovax polio']
```

Comment: print(some_string.split(', ')) works fine. otherwise just split(',') adds a extra space before each string. Anyways, thanks man.

Comment: Good point @Swordsman

Answer (score 4):

Use the split function which breaks the whole string in to sub-string. Also I am using the lstrip function which remove the leading space from the sub-strings.

**Code :**

```
string = 'pentavac-xim, revaxis, tetravac-xim'
value = input_string.split(',')
result = [i.lstrip() for i in output]
print(result)
```

**Output :**

```
['pentavac-xim', 'revaxis', 'tetravac-xim']
```

Comment: most welcome (y)

Answer (score 3):

If you use `.split()` without any argument it will split using the space character. You need to specify with which character you want to split.
For your example you need to split with the comma char like this

```
s = "imogam rage pa, imovax polio"
print(s.split(', '))
['imogam rage pa', 'imovax polio']
```